# producer-consumer with very large items in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm working in the following scenario (with Python). I have a neural net optimised with a stochastic algorithm that needs a constant stream of training data. Each datum is large (let's say 50 megabytes) and I have a lot of data. The entire data set is too large to fit in the RAM. I can see three possible ways of working with this data.

1. Load each datum sequentially from hard drive and then execute the code of the neural net. This is slow for obvious reasons.
2. Use multithreading (threading library). Then I can have multiple threads loading the data from the hard drive and putting them in the queue from which the main process is reading. This is working fairly well though it seems to me that GIL (https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) is slowing me down. The computation of the gradient for the neural net is clearly not really executed in parallel with reading from the hard drive.
3. Use multiprocessing (multiprocessing library). This is analogous to 2. though the implementation of the queue I need to use then is using Linux pipes which are limited to be very small, so the main process spends most of the time reading data from the queue in tiny parts.

All of these ways above are not acceptable for me. Can you think of a more efficient way of implementing such producer-consumer problem in Python?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: divide the data into different files containing, say 5-10 chunks, then use multiprocessing and give only the filename to the subprocess so that he'll open the file and read it concurrently... this reduces the IPC overhead to the minimum while maximizing concurrency.

Comment: @Bakuriu this is more or less, what I am currently doing explained in the third point. The issue with this solution is that (I think) Linux pipes are not designed for transferring very large quantities of data between processes and I believe this is how `multiprocessing.Queue` is implemented, which makes getting what the subprocess read very slow.

Comment: @Deeplearningmaniac I don't think you understood what I said: the only data that you exchange between processes are filenames. You tel the subprocesses the name of the file to read, they read it process the data, save it in an other temporary file and then the main process reads the result fails and does its thing.

Comment: The actual processing can only happen in the main process. I only need reading from the hard drive to be concurrent. The issue I'm trying to explain is that it is very slow to move the data from the child process to the parent process.

Comment: @Deeplearningmaniac First, I think you have to rewrite the question to clarify what you actually want to achieve. Second, if you hit the GIL limitation using threading then reading of data is not a problem, but calculations is, because **GIL doesn't block the I/O**.

Comment: That is not exactly true. The real damage from the GIL is that mixing IO and CPU bound threads makes the IO threads to starve. See http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/